# How to Create a DL knowledge base that encodes the knowledge in the below domain

Tags: nlp

Books are written by one or more authors and are identified by their title. They also belong to one or more genres. Depending on the way they are published, books can be one of three different types: printed, audio or electronic. A book may also be unpublished. Published books have editions, prepared by one assigned editor. Each edition has a number, a date of publication and a date of first publication. In some cases, special editions may be published, as well as “cheap” editions (on low-cost paper and with reduced font size). Both authors and editors are identified by their full name. Newer authors are classified as emerging writers.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: What I posted was a discriptive logic. My aim is to  represent it in TBOX, ABOX using Answer set programming